# How can I assign "selectionMode" only to leaves in a PrimeNG tree?

Tags: angular, frontend, primeng, prime-tree

I have two categories with variable subcategories which have variable sub-subcategories. I want to be able to only select the sub-subcategories, nothing else.

```
p-tree
  [value]="treeItems"
  selectionMode="single"
  [(selection)]="selectedIndicator"
  (onNodeSelect)="nodeSelect()"
>
</p-tree>
```

I tried finding if a class is added to the leaves, but I couldn't figure it out.